# error al sacar dato de una pila C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema al imprimir los datos eliminados de forma iteraria en c++. tengo dos funciones: agregar y eliminar, lo hago con un while( * != NULL), y lo que pasa es que ingreso dos valores; 2 y 5.

El primero en eliminarse es 5, y lo muestra en consola, pero el siguiente dato no se imprimí correctamente, en lugar de imprimir el valor "2", muestra el valor 5; no cambia de valor, y depuré y en la variable dicho valor si cambia, pero no se porque no se imprime correctamente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <new>
using namespace std;


struct nodo{
    int dato;
    nodo *siguienteNodo;
};

void agregarPilla(nodo *&prmPila,int prmValor){
    nodo *nuevoNodo=new nodo();
    nuevoNodo->dato=prmValor;
    nuevoNodo->siguienteNodo=prmPila;
    prmPila=nuevoNodo;
}

void sacarPila(nodo *&pila,int prmValor){
    nodo *aux=pila;
    prmValor=aux->dato;
    pila=aux->siguienteNodo;
    delete aux;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    nodo *pila=NULL;
    int varNumero;
    cout<<"Digite un numero entero:> ";
    cin>>varNumero;
    agregarPilla(pila,varNumero);

    cout<<"Digite un numero entero:> ";
    cin>>varNumero;
    agregarPilla(pila,varNumero);


    cout<<"--------------------------------------";


    cout<<"SACAR VALOR DE LA PILA\n";
    while(pila!=NULL){         //mientras no sea el final de la pila
        sacarPila(pila,varNumero);
            if(pila!=NULL){
                cout<<varNumero<<",";  // en este paso varNumero sigue teniendo el mismo valor del primer dato de la pila
            }else{
                cout<<varNumero<<".";
            }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `varNumero` siempre se pasa por valor, esto quiere decir que el segundo parámetro de la función `sacarPila` recibe una copia del contenido de `varNumero`.

Entonces cuando se ejecute esta línea:

```cpp
prmValor=aux->dato;
```

Se le asigna el dato al parámetro, sin embargo, cuando la función finaliza, los recursos (parámetros, variables locales, etc.) que ocupaba la función se libera de la memoria.

**Solución:** Debes pasar por referencia. Así que el encabezado de la función `sacarPila` debería de quedar así:

```cpp
void sacarPila(nodo *&pila, int& prmValor)
```

El ampersand(`&`) indica que `prmValor` es una referencia a `int`. Entonces cuando se ejecute esta línea:

```cpp
prmValor=aux->dato;
```

Estarías enviando el dato a la variable (que vendría ser `varNumero`) que pasaste por referencia.